# How much tables approximativly in the designer will make Visual Studio slow?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I was wondering if my database got way too much table for use the designer. **Would be glad to hear experience from those that using L2Q with lots of tables.**

1. How much table your database have ?
2. How fast is VB ? (fast, experiencing slowdowns, unusable)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got 700+ tables in the dbml file in one project. Works fine.
After Adding/Deleting tables from the designer it takes 3-4 seconds to save the file.